# c# datatable left join in this example

Tags: c#, datatable

I have this code

```
var result = (from row1 in table.AsEnumerable()
                          join row2 in tabelPopup.AsEnumerable()
                          on row1.Field<string>("CallID") equals
                          row2.Field<string>("callID")
                          where row1.Field<string>("Direction") == "I"
                          select new
                          {
                              Agent = row1.Field<string>("Agent"),
                              StartTime = row1.Field<string>("StartTime"),
                              Reason = row2.Field<string>("Reason")
                          });
```

where `table` and `tablePopup` are datatables,

as you see, I am doing join. I would like to do a left join, could u help me plesae?

I read a lot and I found that I have to do a `join` and a `into`, then do the `into name` with `.DefaultOfEmpty()` function, but I couldn't

Comment: Have you tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

Comment: @artm yes I already read that link, and as I told u in the question, I couldn't apply that solution, my situation is much more complex than that

Comment: What was the problem when you tried DefaultIfEmpty?

Comment: @artm I kept having the same results, join but not left join

Comment: So when you try DefaultIfEmpty, you get the same result as you get without DefaultIfEmpty? Show us the code you tried and its results.

Comment: @artm I already showed u the whole code

Comment: What result did you get when you tried it with DefaultIfEmpty? Error? Incorrect values? How did you implement DefaultIfEmpty?

Answer (score 0):

```
var left_outer_join = 
    from row1 in table.AsEnumerable() 
    join row2 in tabelPopup.AsEnumerable()
    on row1.Field<string>("CallID") equals row2.Field<string>("callID")
    into outJoin
    where row1.Field<string>("Direction") == "I"
    from oj in outJoin.DefaultIfEmpty() 
    select new {
        Agent = row1.Field<string>("Agent"),
        StartTime = row1.Field<string>("StartTime"),
        Reason = (oj == null) 
            ? String.Empty 
            : oj.Field<string>("Reason") 
    };
```